# Troubleshooting Help: Fedora to Windows Share Move Failure from Crontab Script

Tags: fedora, mount, cron

My crontab script started failing recently on a move command from the local file system to a windows mount with the following error:

```
mv: closing `/mnt/SEProjbackups/20101124-040001_vm-seprojects.tar.bz2': Input/output error
```

Both the local and remote servers have adequate disk space. The file is copied and is the correct size, but the archive is corrupt. Meanwhile if I run the move from the command line it works.

Any suggestions I on what I should do to troubleshoot? I am a Linux noob, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it fail every time? How is the windows mount mounted? What are the export permissions on the mount?

Rather than using `mv`, I'd suggest using rsync, which will checksum the file and make sure it transferred successfully, and which can resume partially-transferred files. The incantation I think you want is:

```
rsync --partial --times --remove-sent-files  /location/of/SEProj/* /mnt/SEProjbackups/
```

Consult the rsync man page for other options you might want to add.

This will attempt to move *any* files in `/location/of/SEProj/` (use the real path, of course) to your mounted share, and remove what transfers successfully.

That way, even if this problem is just a transient glitch, you'll get all the backups transferred eventually.

Comment: +1 thanks for the idea. It started consistently failing and then I changed the crontab time and now it succeeds again; so, suspecting other network traffic is to blame. I'll investigate rsync.